# Use regex to access object's fields

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am in a situation in which I may need to process a JSON that could contain varying key names, which I'd need to access via regex.

For simplicity, I could receive a list similar to:

```
x=[{  bus: "XYZ123", color:"red"   },
  {  minibus: "ZZZ999", color:"blue"   } ]
```

and I need to have a function that could get XYZ123 and ZZZ999 within a map function.

I've tried `x.map( e => e[/.*bus/])` but to no avail, returning `[undefined,undefined]`

Does anyone have any trick I could follow for this?

Thank you

Comment: How "varying" are we talking about?  If it is a finite list, you could just look for any of them.

Comment: What did you get when you first tried?

Comment: It's varying enough to not be able to set up a finite list

Comment: Then first off I would question why that is.  And secondly, if that is the only dynamic one, you could look for any key, excluding the `color` key.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = [{
    bus: "XYZ123",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    minibus: "ZZZ999",
    color: "blue"
  }
];

console.log(
  x.map(it => it[Object.keys(it).find(key => key.endsWith('bus'))])
);
```

This version of the logic gets all the keys, and then finds the key that ends with bus.  Assuming there is only one per object, it gets the first one, and then returns that keys value in each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for ... in loop to find a property name on an object by matching a regular expression.

```
const regex = /.*bus/;

const result = x.map((e) => {
  for (var key in e) {
    if (key.match(regex)) {
      return e[key];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map return mapping... one to one. so if some of your data in array don't fulfills your condition then you return an undefined value on this index in array. eg.if you have array that have 100 items, and only 5 fulfills your condition, then a map will return 100 elements in 95 cases you will get undefined. You should use filter, if you need a new copy of your array you can just create it.

```js
const x=[{  bus: "XYZ123", color:"red"   },
  {  minibus: "ZZZ999", color:"blue"   } ,
  {  motobicke: "ZZZ999", color:"black"   } ]
 

const filterBy = (data, regex) => {
  return Array.from(data).filter(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => regex.test(key)) )
}

console.log(filterBy(x, /bus/));
```